# Font Awesome CSS overriding my CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-awesome

I am working on a page - [click here for link](https://www.agentpro.co.uk/marketing-overview/). The icons are all supposed to have the font size of .side-icon:

```
.side-icon{ 
    font-size:28px;
}
```

BUT a style in font-awesome.css is overriding this, no matter where I include the library in the layout.

At the moment I have included the css in the top of a work around sheet (font-awesome-fix.css) using an @import, but I cannot get the 'font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;' to disappear at all.

Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your selector more specific :

```
.side-icon.fa
```

See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) how the priorities of the selectors are calculated.

Comment: This fixed it! I've been staring at my style sheets for an hour tearing my hair out. Thank you!

Comment: @asoxus Great ! I added a documentation to understand why this works.

Answer (score 2):

Hey you should target the before element :

```
.side-icon:before{ 
    font-size:28px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe try adding an id to the specific .side-icon that you need to change the font on.
CSS:

```
.side-icon #id_goes_here{
font-size:14px;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The very helpful "!important" usually helps me solve issues like this, or at least determine the root issue:

```
.side-icon{ 
   font-size:28px !important;
}
```

Comment: http://www.impressivewebs.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-important-css-declaration/

Comment: !important is the devil!

Comment: yes but he/it can help you solve problems sometimes ... then just remove it

Answer (score 0):

Try using more specific css to override the other styles. This may include adding classes or ids so you can chain them together to override.

Examples:

```
.side-icon.foo{styles}
#bar.side-icon{styles}
```

If that still doesn't work, you may want to use the !important override to add another layer of specificity. I wouldn't reccomend jumping to use it immediately, but that's mostly because i prefer to code more specifically than using !important everywhere.

Example:

```
.side-icon{style:value!important;}
```

If neither of these work, there may be other issues messing with your styles.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the CSS specificity rule kicks in:

> When selectors have an equal specificity value, the latest rule is the
>   one that counts.

So including your file at the topmost location does not help because the `font-awesome.css` gets included later and since both `.side-icon` and `.fa` are classes on the same element, `.fa` defined by `font-awesome.css` got picked up by the browser because `.fa` was the latest font-size definition.

So, in order to overcome this problem, include your `font-awesome-fix.css` after `font-awesome.css` or you could use inline style after the line that includes font-swesome.css

```
<style>
  .side-icon {
     font-size: 28px;
  }
</style>
```

or override the .fa font declaration in the same file (if you have control over it) by ensuring that the font-size override comes after the original declaration

or use one of the several ways to become more specific (see CSS specificity[1])

[1] http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity